# Windows 10: Microsoft Store, Edge and Photos open by themselves randomly

Tags: windows-10

While working on the laptop, some apps like Microsoft Store and Edge open randomly and keep on doing so at the interval of 30 minutes or so.

I was looking this Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3fivhh/windows_10_photo_and_store_apps_opening_by/

The DisplayFusion was creating the problem in the above case. Since I am using Dexpot, I believe that it has to do something with the problem I am facing. But I can't figure out how to deal with it. Does anyone know the fix to this issue?